# Automatically print each of the function name when the function is traversed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Are there anyway for Ruby/Rails to automatically print the function name when I pass the function for easily debugging? As I found it is troublesome to add puts before each function. Please advise and thanks!

Example:

```
def update_original_calendar
  puts '-> update_original_calendar'
end

def update_destination_calendar
  puts '-> update_destination_calendar'
  update_original_calendar
end
```

Result of Example:

```
-> update_destination_calendar
-> update_original_calendar
```

Comment: Isn't this what the debugger is for?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [`Kernel#set_trace_func`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-set_trace_func) method. Put the following code somewhere in your initializing logic. Just ensure that when application logic reaches the method you want to trace, that piece of code has been executed.

```
classes_to_trace = %w(YOUR_CLASSNAME1 YOUR_CLASSNAME2)
set_trace_func proc {|event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  if event == 'call' and classes_to_trace.include?(classname.to_s)
    puts "event = #{event}, file = #{file}, line = #{line}, id = #{id}, classname = #{classname}"
  end
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 2.x:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/TracePoint.html

```
trace = TracePoint.new(:call) do |tp|
    p [tp.lineno, tp.defined_class, tp.method_id, tp.event]
end

trace.enable

# Your code here
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work